# How can i hold my datas in page when ı change active page in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, tabs, components

I'm using material ui tabs and i have 8 pages in tabs. Every page is a component. And when i changed active tab, I call another component .There are inputs area in my pages so when i changed tabs and return previes tab, my old datas clear. so ı want to hold my input datas when pass to another tab. how can ı hold my data?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to use `redux`. Save form data in redux and use them when you load the component to set initial data.

Answer (score 0):

For the global client state, I can recommend **Recoil**, Redux, or MobX. For server state, I suggest you look at **React-query** or SWR.